# Checkbox Muliple select using shift key in gridview asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Iam using vs 2010 with C#.I want to select muliple rows checked using shift key in grid view

i tried using java script but not working

Here is my grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   CssClass="normtxt"
                                     HeaderStyle-BackColor="#819FF7" ShowFooter="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" EmptyDataText="No records found" 
                                     OnRowCancelingEdit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit" 
                                     OnRowDeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting"
                                    OnRowEditing="gvDetails_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="gvDetails_RowCommand">
                                     <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" BorderColor="#7BA1C3" />
                                       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7BA1C3" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" CssClass="lockHeadDivdgrid" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="All"   AutoPostBack="true"
                                                    OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_OnCheckedChanged" />
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" onclick='<%# string.Format("javascript:selectCheckbox(this,{0});", Container.DataItemIndex) %>' runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_OnCheckedChanged" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ParagraphStyle" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblParagraphStyle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ParagraphStyle") %>' />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtParagraphStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParagraphStyle") %>'
                                                    Visible="false" CssClass="txt_1"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxParaRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtParagraphStyle"
                                                    FirstRowSelected="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblParent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Parent") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtParent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Parent") %>' Visible="false" CssClass="txt_1" />
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxParentRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtParent" FirstRowSelected="true"
                                                    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnCriteria" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfnCriteria" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fnCriteria") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnCriteria" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fnCriteria") %>' Visible="false"
                                                    CssClass="txt_1" />
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender3" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxfnCriteriaRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtfnCriteria"
                                                    FirstRowSelected="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnCase" ItemStyle-Width="10" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfnCase" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Eval("fnCase") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnCase" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fnCase") %>' Visible="false" CssClass="txt_1" />
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender4" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxfnCaseRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtfnCase" FirstRowSelected="true"
                                                    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnFormat" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfnFormat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fnFormat") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnFormat" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fnFormat") %>' Visible="false" CssClass="txt_1" />
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender5" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxfnFormatRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtfnFormat" FirstRowSelected="true"
                                                    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And my javascript is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var startingIndex = 0, gridViewID = '<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>';
     function selectCheckbox(checkbox, selectedInded) {
         alert(gridViewID);
           if (event.shiftKey) {
               //shift end
               alert("");
               if (startingIndex < selectedInded)
               //forward
                   $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(startingIndex, selectedInded).prop("checked", true);
               else
               //backward
                   $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(selectedInded, startingIndex).prop("checked", true);
           }
           startingIndex = selectedInded;
       }
</script>
```

Suggest me to get a solution .
thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve. Can you explain more? Do you want to use shift key to click on just the last CheckBox and select all the CheckBoxes in the range?

Comment: yes i want to select all the CheckBoxes in the range

Comment: Experts Please Suggest here

Comment: Don't worry, I'm also an expert ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access event object like that. It is only defined in the scope of the event handler, in this case the code inside `onclick` attribute value. If you want to call another function from there, you should pass the `event` object as an argument.

And also you are mixing client and server-side events which does not seem to be what you want, so I removed the server event handler and set `AutoPostBack` to `false`.

Your checkbox in the markup code becomes:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" onclick='<%# string.Format("javascript:selectCheckbox(event,{0});", Container.DataItemIndex) %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

And your script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var startingIndex = 0, gridViewID = '<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>';
     function selectCheckbox(e, selectedIndex) {
           if (e.shiftKey) { alert("shift pressed");
               if (startingIndex < selectedIndex)
               {
                   alert( $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).length);
                   $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(startingIndex, selectedIndex).prop("checked", true);
               }
               else
                   $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(selectedIndex, startingIndex).prop("checked", true);
           }
           startingIndex = selectedIndex;
       }
</script>
```

This is my test which is working fine. I used a simple `DataSource`, but that will work with any other source as well. Just to give you the correct direction.

WebForm1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var startingIndex = 0, gridViewID = '<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>';
     function selectCheckbox(e, selectedIndex) {
         if (e.shiftKey) {
             alert("shift pressed");
             if (startingIndex < selectedIndex) {
                 alert($(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).length);
                 $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(startingIndex, selectedIndex).prop("checked", true);
             }
             else
                 $(':checkbox', '#' + gridViewID).slice(selectedIndex, startingIndex).prop("checked", true);
         }
         startingIndex = selectedIndex;
     }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" onclick='<%# string.Format("javascript:selectCheckbox(event,{0});", Container.DataItemIndex) %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvDetails.DataSource = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            gvDetails.DataBind();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit strange, what happens? do you get an error message?

Comment: Codebehind will ruin this for you. Let's put some alerts to see what's happening. Will update the answer

Comment: And something else: can you please get the web page source out of your browser and paste the part with `gvDetails`?

Comment: Do you want my simplified we page to give  you the idea?

Comment: Yeah, give your web page

Comment: No, yar i left that issue